# Why can't I click between windows after Xenial (16.04) update?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, bugs

I recently updated to Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial, and since then, I have been unable to click between windows. For example, I have a Chrome window up, open Sublime Text, and try to click Sublime (or Chrome) and neither focuses. I have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus either window.

I also notice that when logging in, I cannot click the user account to get the password check. I have to highlight the account (w/ arrows) & hit enter.

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome on an HP EliteBook (which was working before the update). Both mouse and trackpad are unable to focus the windows (click events are definitely working though).

I've also submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1574800), but thought I'd check here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix, although I don't understand it. I had to change which *NVIDIA* driver I was using.

From...

`Using NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.131 from nvidia-304 (proprietary)`

... to ...

`Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 361.42 from nvidia-361 (proprietary, tested)`

To change this, I went to **Software & Updates > Additional Drivers (Tab)**.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!   
I have a GTX 660 that is supposedly needs the 304 driver.